# how to write cookie test in javascript supported for all browsers

Tags: javascript

I used below code to check whether cookies is enabled or not in browsers:

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
  try {
    document.cookie = 'cookietest=1';
    console.log(document.cookie.indexOf('cookietest=') !== -1)
    var cookiesEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf('cookietest=') !== -1;
    document.cookie = 'cookietest=1; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';
    return cookiesEnabled;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(areCookiesEnabled());
```

The issue here is that above code always returns `false` in Chrome (even when enabling or disabling the cookie) and in IE (11, 9, 8) and Edge always returns `true` (even when enabling or disabling the cookie). The code is working fine only in Mozilla. Can anyone post a code to detect whether the cookie is enabled or not supported in all browsers?

Comment: Works fine in my case, what the's issue you're getting? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: @deathangel908 do you check it with by disabling/enabling the cookie in chrome.In my case it always returning false.

Comment: use your IP address  as domain instead of localhost to store your cookies and let me know.

Comment: @pranabvv set the cookie, then go to devconsole -> applications and check  in cookies section if it's set.